# SwipeRefreshLayout does not exist on Visual Studio + Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a problem when I'm trying to run my program on my phone. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin for developing android app.  I got this error :

> error: package android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout does not exist
>           android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener

Here is my [References Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Vlm.png), I already added Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 and Xamarin.Android.Support.V13 and this is my [SDK Manager Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uqMT.png)

Does anyone see anything that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A downloaded package (zip file) from Google is truncated/corrupt and does not inflate properly can cause this.

#### Try:

---

- Remove the Nuget package and re-add it. Perform a clean all/build all on your solution

#### Otherwise:

---

- Check the following location:

---

```
C:\Users\[YourUserID]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\[Version])
```

---

You can delete those files, restart Visual Studio and perform a clean all/build all on your solution and those support files will be downloaded and cached from Google again.